# How do i check a list (T) of tuples up against a list (H), followed by extracting +-5 of these tuples in list which corresponds with element in H)?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, tuples

I haven't done much list/tuple checking and i wanted to try it.
I want to extract elements from list, compare lists containing tuples and add some statement to them.

```
count1 = 100
theCounter = range(count1)
rsData = 56
T = []
R = [56,112,168,224,280]
H = [95,74,53,32,11]
for i in theCounter:
    T.append((count1,rsData))
    count1 = count1 - 1
    if (count1/25).is_integer() :
        rsData = rsData + 56
    
print(R)
print(H)
print(T)
```

Here is the problem:

T is a list of tuples. [(100, 56), (99, 56), (98, 56), (97, 56), (96, 56), (95, 56), (94, 56), (93, 56), (92, 56), (91, 56), (90, 56), (89, 56), (88, 56), (87, 56), (86, 56), (85, 56), (84, 56), (83, 56), (82, 56), (81, 56), (80, 56), (79, 56), (78, 56), (77, 56), (76, 56), (75, 112), (74, 112), (73, 112), (72, 112), (71, 112), (70, 112), (69, 112), (68, 112), (67, 112), (66, 112),....]

I want to search the first element in each tuple in T (this, notThis) and extract the tuples that corresponds with list H and make new lists. Followed by this i want the 5 elements before and 5 elements after.

Example: from H[1] = 74
list_H_74 = [(79, 56), (78, 56), (77, 56), (76, 56), (75, 112), (74, 112), (73, 112), (72, 112), (71, 112), (70, 112), (69, 112)]

After this i want to check list_H_74 2nd tuple elements (rsData) up against my element in list R, which must correspond with the element in H.
Example: if R[1] = 112 (check against H[1] (list_H_74))
list_R_112_H_74 =

This list_R_112_H_74 need some conditions:

- 2nd tuple's (rsData) in list_R_112_H_74 must be 112 == R[1] before or where the first tuple's reaches 75 == H[1]
- if it has reached 112 it can't go back to 56

How do i complete this task without making hundreds of unnecessary lines with code?

Probably not the easiest qeustion on here, but maybe there is some smart fucntions to use when comparing lists.

I tried stack overflow, but there aren't many questions on here where they are comparing tuples and lists this advanced.

Comment: Please add proper formatting to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with from my understanding of your problem, but it's not clear what you want the output to look like.

```py
output = {
    f"{x}": [y for y in T if y[0] >= x - 5 and y[0] <= x + 5 and y[1] == R[H.index(x)]]
    for x in H
}
print(output)
```

Explanation:

- For each item in H, create a list
- The list should be populated with tuples from T where both of the following conditions are met:

  - The first item in the tuple should be within +/- 5 of the item from H
  - The second item in the tuple should be the value from the same index in R

Output:

```
{'95': [(100, 56), (99, 56), (98, 56), (97, 56), (96, 56), (95, 56), (94, 56), (93, 56), (92, 56), (91, 56), (90, 56)], '74': [(75, 112), (74, 112), (73, 112), (72, 112), (71, 112), (70, 112), (69, 112)], '53': [(50, 168), (49, 168), (48, 168)], '32': [], '11': []}
```

Comment: I get list index out of range. To explain it better. The extracted list from T using H +/-5 is okay. But this list needs the bring along the whole tuple. Afterwards i want to CHECK the 2nd tuple elements in that extracted list from T using H, up against the R list, while using the same index as H. ''95': [(100, 56), (99, 56), (98, 56), (97, 56), (96, 56), (95, 56), (94, 56), (93, 56), (92, 56), (91, 56), (90, 56)]' is +/-5 from T using H[0] as reference so OK. Now i need to check this list if R[0] exist in the second tuples (rsData) and same with every element in H and R.

Comment: That's what `and y[1] == R[H.index(x)]` is doing. It's checking if the second item from the tuple matches the same index from R.

Comment: Is your data somehow different than the example? I just added my code to the end of yours without changing anything and I get no errors. If you're getting index out of range, it sounds like R and H are probably not the same length

Comment: Okay i see. This was really helpful Nathan. Is it possible to print out a list a checklist. With just the R and H list and a new list that prints all the checked numbers and status (OK or NOK) notation behind them to .txt within this function of yours?